# a global variable in an included file not available in another

Tags: php, variables, scope, include

In php I have a page index1.php that starts like this:

```
require_once ('mysql_connect.php'); 
require_once ('includes/login_functions.inc.php');
```

In my mysql_connect.php, the last two lines are:

```
global $dbc;
$dbc = connect_to_db(); ?>
```

Now, in login_functions.inc.php I use $dbc within a function, but I get the following error:

```
Undefined variable: dbc in /var/www/[a few sub directories]/includes/login_functions.inc.php
```

Why can't login_functions.inc.php see $dbc?
What am I missing?

Comment: place the global *after* the method

Comment: and if not that ^ then show us where you're using that method and how

Comment: Ok, I've posted 2 comments with no response and you've been given an answer below. Whether it will still be there when you get back, is anyone's guess. I have now left the question and closed your question. Consult the duplicates.

Comment: Thank you. The answer was indeed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32678766/715582